# Мне не за чем / незачем было приходить — он уже всё сделал

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Мне не за чем / незачем было приходить — он уже всё сделал.

Comment: Орфографический словарь:
незачем (нет смысла, надобности: незачем спрашивать), но местоим. не за чем (не за чем спрятаться)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Мне незачем (= не было причины) было приходить — он уже всë сделал*.

*Мне не за чем было приходить — он уже всë сделал* — то есть нет какого-то предмета, за которым нужно прийти. Функция местоимения.

Comment: Странное предложение. Тогда контекст нужен для его понимания. Напишите, пожалуйста.